# Effective way of distributing go executable

Tags: go, installation, cross-platform, software-distribution

I have a go app which relies heavily on static resources like images and jars. I want to install that go executable in different platforms like linux, mac and windows.

- I first thought of bundling the resources using https://github.com/jteeuwen/go-bindata, but since the files(~100) have size ~ 20MB or so, it takes a really long time to build the executable. I thought having a single executable is an easy way for people to download the executable and run it. But seems like that is not an effective way.
- I then thought of writing a installation package for each of the platform like creating a .rpm or .deb packages? So these packages contain all the resources and puts it into some platform specific pre defined locations and the go executable can reference them. But the only   thing is that I have to handle that in the go code. I have to see if it is windows then load the files from say c:\go-installs or if it is linux then load the files from say /usr/local/share/go-installs. I want the go code to be as platform agnostic as it can be.

Or is there some other strategy for this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Possibly does not qualify as real answer but still…

- As to your point №2, one way to handle this is to exploit [Go's way to do conditional compilation](http://golang.org/pkg/go/build/#hdr-Build_Constraints): you might create a set of files like `res_linux.go`, `res_windows.go` etc and put a set of the same variables in each, pointing to different locations, like

  ```
  var InstallsPath = `C:\go-installs`
  ```

  in `res_windows.go` and

  ```
  var InstallsPath = `/usr/share/myapp`
  ```

  in `res_linux.go` and so on.  Then in the rest of the program just reference the `res.InstallsPath` variable and use the [`path/filepath`](http://golang.org/pkg/path/filepath) package to construct full pathnames of actual resources.

  Of course, another way to go is to do a runtime switch on [`runtime.GOOS`](http://golang.org/pkg/runtime) variable—possibly in an `init()` function in one of the source files.
- Pack everything in a `zip` archive and read your resource files from it using [`archive/zip`](http://golang.org/pkg/archive/zip).  This way you'll have to distribute just two files—*almost* "xcopy deployment".

  Note that while on Windows you could just have your executable extract the directory from the pathname of itself (`os.Args[0]`) and assume the resource file is located in the same directory, on POSIX platforms (GNU/Linux and *BSD etc) the resource file should still be located under `/usr/share/myapp` or a similar place dictated by [FHS](http://www.pathname.com/fhs/) (or [particular distro's rules](https://www.debian.org/doc/debian-policy/ch-sharedlibs.html#s-sharedlibs-support-files)), so some logic to locate that file will still be required.

All in all, if this is supposed to be a piece of [FOSS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_and_open-source_software), I'd go with the first variant to let the downstream packagers tweak the pathnames.  If this is a proprietary (or just niche) software the second idea appears to be rather OK as you'll play the role of downstream packagers yourself.